# Spring batch: SkipListener implemented - But onSkipInWrite() method throwing same message for entire batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am working on Spring Batch : I am reading Data from a FlatFile and using Jdbc connection saving the record read from the file to the Database. While doing that I have configured a listener that will be called if an error has being generated while reading or writing the data. I am uploading 10 records into the database in which 2 record have an error. It is inserting 8 records properly as we needed, but the onSkipInWrite() method does not give out the 2 record that were skipped actually, but it prints out the entire batch of 10 recordes with same exception with it . How should I filter out which record is not being skipped actually the method says that you will get the exact record that is being skipped in the entire batch.  Please help me ....Waiting for kind response.....Thanks

Configured in Audit.xml
Sample example:

```
<step id="step1" >
        <tasklet allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <chunk reader="Reader" writer="Writer" commit-interval="10" skip-limit="10">
                <skippable-exception-classes>
                    <include class="java.lang.Exception" />
                </skippable-exception-classes>
            </chunk>
            <listeners>
                <listener ref="Listener" />
            </listeners>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
```

I have written a Listener class below is the sample:

```
public class Listener implements SkipListener {


    @Override
    public void onSkipInProcess(Object item, Throwable throw) {
        System.out.print ("Error in the record :" + item.gettoString() + " Type of Error : " + throw.getClass());

    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInRead(Throwable throw) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInWrite(Object item, Throwable throw) {

     System.out.print ("Error in the record :" + item.gettoString() + " Type of Error : " + throw.getClass());

}

}
```

Comment: Where does your skip occur? When reading the item from the flat file? Then you should probably use the `onSkipInRead` method. You did not declare any item processors btw, so `onSkipInProcess` will never be called. `onSkipInWrite` will only be called, if an exception is raised within the item writer, while you persist your entity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `skip-limit="10"`

use

```
                <batch:skip-policy>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy" scope="step"/>
                </batch:skip-policy>
```